# hover bold moves my li links

Tags: html, css, hover

I have problem with my menu, because I want to bold effect on hover, yes it is but my others links are moving.

my code :

```
ul.menu-top{
    float:left;
    margin-left:71px;
    }
ul.menu-top li{float:left; 
margin-left:33px; 
}
ul.menu-top li a{
font: 14px/16px Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; 
color:#444343;    
display:inline-block;
text-align:center;
padding: 0px;
}
ul.menu-top li a:hover{
color:#e0aa71;
padding: 0px;
font-weight:bold;   
}
    ul.menu-top li a:after{
    display:block;
    content:attr(title);
    font-weight:bold;
    height:1px;
    padding: 0px;

    color:transparent;
    overflow:hidden;
    visibility:hidden;}
ul.menu-top li a:hover:after{font-weight:bold;}
```

[My top menu](http://realizacje.compute-web.net/nozebijakowe/)
[jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/8HKT7/)

Comment: I think this conversation covers the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/556153/horiz-css-menu-text-shifting-on-bold-hover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your style to

```
ul.menu-top{
    float:left;
    margin-left:61px;
    }
ul.menu-top li{float:left; 
margin-left:15px; 
width: 65px;
}
```

and also change the first `li` inline style to

```
style="margin:0;width:105px"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
ul.menu-top li a:hover{font-weight:bold;}
```

Instead of:

```
ul.menu-top li a:hover:after{font-weight:bold;}
```

Comment: Can you create a Fiddle of your code please? or proved the HTML as well so I can test it myself?

Answer (score 0):

```
font-weight:bold;
```

Giving a bold effect to the text makes it bigger, so no surprise it ruins your layout.
I always try to avoid that and use instead different colors to make it stand out.