# CSS hover state - prevent shakiness of other elements

Tags: html, css, font-size

When one of the links is hovered, rest of the elements slightly move to left coz of the change in `font-weight` on the hovered link.

This is what I tried

HTML

```
<div id="footer"> &copy; GreatService <a href="">Terms</a>&middot;<a href="">Privacy</a>&middot;<a href="">Legal</a>&middot;<a href="">Company</a>&middot;<a href="">Media</a>&middot;<a href="">Technology</a>&middot;<a href="">FAQ</a> &middot; Made with <span>&hearts;</span>. Enjoy!</div>
```

CSS

```
    #footer {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 20px;}

    #footer, #footer a {
      color: #fff;}

    #footer a {
      margin-left: 5px;margin-right:5px;text-decoration: none;padding-left: 3px;padding-right: 3px;
    }
    #footer a:hover {
      font-weight: 700;

    }
    #footer a:hover a{padding-left: 2px; }

    #footer span {
      color: red;}
```

Any way to prevent shakiness of the other elements, so it looks as if the hovered link is being emphasized in its own place without causing any disturbance to the position of the other non-hovered links?

http://jsfiddle.net/sjeojvos/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Horiz CSS menu - text shifting on bold hover](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/556153/horiz-css-menu-text-shifting-on-bold-hover)

Comment: Lot of useful answers in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/556153/horiz-css-menu-text-shifting-on-bold-hover). Ignore the accepted answer, there are plenty of interesting workarounds.

Comment: Have you even read my code? I tried preserving some space for the `bold` state, somehow it is getting close but not exactly perfect.

Comment: I've looked at your fiddle and your code. You're trying to calculate your way out if it by adapting the padding. The increase in width caused by setting the font weight to bold will depend on the length of the word, so any calculation will be iffy. Oh, and your `padding-left: 2px` rule will not get applied due to the extra `a`.

Comment: Changed it to - `#footer a:hover ~ a{padding-left: 2px; }`. It is somewhat stable, but not perfect

Comment: Here's an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sjeojvos/1/) with one of the recommendations from the referenced question.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a copy of the element and change the `position: absolute` on `:hover`

The HTML:

```
<div>
    <span class="body">Link 1</span>
    <span class="shadow">Link 1</span>
</div> *
```

The CSS:

```
div{
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 32px;
}

div:hover .body{
    font-weight: bold;
    position: absolute;
}

div:hover .shadow{
    display: initial;
}

.shadow{
    color: white;
    display: none;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1bdmgt8n/2/