# Disable not working for my button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been trying to make my own button and for some reason I don't seem to get the :disable to work right. I want the button to be disabled (not respond to click and grey text). What am I missing?

http://jsfiddle.net/aj4n0ymd/

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<div id="menu"> 
    <a class="button" disabled="true" id="button">Click</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.button {
    display: block;
    width: 40%;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 10px;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Chrome/Safari */
    -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
    -ms-user-select: none; /* IE10+ */
/* Rules below not implemented in browsers yet */
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
.button:hover {
    background: #f0f0f0;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.button:active {
    background: rgb(150, 150, 150);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(150, 150, 150), rgb(200, 200, 200));
    text-decoration: none;
}
.button:disabled {
    color:rgb(150, 150, 150);
}
```

Also, this is going to be used with javascript. Is this enough in the js to change the disabled state?

```
button = document.querySelector("#button");
button.disabled = true;
```

Comment: <a /> does not have disabled attribute ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [**a**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Attributes) tag doesn't have a disabled attribute. Take a look to the doc for the valid attributes that can have. Only `inputs` or `select` or `textareas` can have disabled attribute.

You can remove `href` or add a click handler that returns false.

```js
$("#button").on("click", function() {
  alert("ok");
});
```

```css
.button {
  display: block;
  width: 40%;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 10px;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  /* Chrome/Safari */
  -moz-user-select: none;
  /* Firefox */
  -ms-user-select: none;
  /* IE10+ */
  /* Rules below not implemented in browsers yet */
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
}
.button:hover {
  background: #f0f0f0;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.button:active {
  background: rgb(150, 150, 150);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(150, 150, 150), rgb(200, 200, 200));
  text-decoration: none;
}
.button:disabled {
  color: rgb(150, 150, 150);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu" disabled="disabled">
  <input type="button" class="button" id="button" disabled="disabled" value="Click" />
</div>
```

**References**

[MDN `<a>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Attributes)

Comment: In the end I did not use your solution, but your remark about the <a> tag not having the disabled attribute made me look for more information and eventually I landed on this site:

http://davidwalsh.name/html5-buttons

Which I believe is a really nice explanation.
Using a button caused 2 problems:
During hover, it moved other elements. (solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/556153/horiz-css-menu-text-shifting-on-bold-hover)
Buttons have a border by default, but for that it's just a matter of doing button { border:0;}.

Comment: Hope you see this one [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Attributes) :)

Answer (score 5):

In your HTML :

The correct way is `disabled="disabled"` instead of this `disabled="true"` but this doesn't do anything for a `<a...></a>` link.

You can add an `onclick` event to avoid the link to redirect :

```
<a class="button" onclick"return false;" id="button">Click</a>
```

Then in your CSS, just replace the `color` property with a grey color for your button :

```
.button {
  ...
  color: grey;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's simple, your element must have to be a button

```
<!doctype html>
<div id="menu"> 
    <button class="button" disabled="disabled" id="button">Click</button>

</div>
```

Working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/aj4n0ymd/3/

Answer (score 0):

does not have disabled attribute ...
if you need to disable the click event on a you can use JQuery's preventDefault() on click event:

```
$( "a" ).click(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

as per [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

Answer (score 0):

it should be button or anchor tag with little bit javascript.

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/QGWcn/
[Jsfiddle]

```
$('#link').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
```

});