# Font Weight bold on select element

Tags: css

I am having problems with `font-weight` on a `select` element. when applying `font-weight: bold;` the last letter gets cut off, because its bumping in to the right side. I searched and did not find any answer, even though it sounds like a problem that a lot of people have experienced, thanks.

```css
select{
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<select>
    <option>Option</option>
</select>
```

Here is a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pdg6805/3v58gsqm/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NQxRA/1/

Comment: Please look at the edited question, thanks

Comment: ...In which browser?  Looks OK to me in Firefox and Chrome.  (Could it also be only true for some fonts?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simplest way is to add width to select.

```css
select{
    font-weight: bold;
    width:150px;
}
```

```html
    <select>
     <option>Option &nbsp;</option>
   </select>
```

Or

```css
select {
   font-weight:bold;
  }
```

```html
    <select>
     <option>Option &nbsp;</option>
   </select>
```

Comment: the second one is a better option as you don't have to set an explicit height!! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

sometimes in some cases applying `bold` to `font-weight` will change the width of that element and being wider causes cutting off, so you could reserve some more space for it by setting `width` in select.

Comment: This is the exact issue I have, nothing more nothing less

Comment: @daveguru this may helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/556153/inline-elements-shifting-when-made-bold-on-hover