# How to stop the movement of box on hover?

Tags: html, css, hover

I have a box in where there is a `READ MORE` text. Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/csybh5ze/1/) for it. On hover, the box is moving towards the right. I am wondering what is the reason behind this ? `How can I stop its movement ?`

Below is my css code:

```
.chrisdavenport-middle24-text{
   position: absolute;
    top: 290px;
    /* font-style: italic; */
    font-family: "Adelle PE";
    padding-right: 200px;
    /* font-size: 16px; */
    padding-left: 200px;
    border-style: solid;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
   color: orange;
    line-height: 1.379;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: "Adelle PE";
   color: red;
    right: 35px;
    letter-spacing: 0.300em;
}

.chrisdavenport-middle24-text:hover {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic; 
}
```

Comment: This css is for text , can you show css code of box

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/556153/3597276

Comment: @AkhilTrivedi That's the only CSS I have and you can check my jsfiddle example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The box isn't moving, it's just getting a little bit wider (right aligned, so the left border goes to the left a little bit). That's due to the bold and italic font taking a little more horizontal space than the regular font.

To avoid this, you can use a fixed width on the box: Erase the `padding-right` and `padding-left`and give it `text-align: center` and an appropriate `width` setting.

Here's the according fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ghwzzyjy/1/

Answer (score 1):

The box isn't actually moving, it's just getting wider because you're changing the weight and style of the font. To resolve this bug you just need to either assign your paragraph tag a "width" property, or imply that width by giving it a "left" property, to compliment the "right" counterpart you're already using above. Doing this will constrain it's width and stop the box from changing size.

```
.chrisdavenport-middle24-text{
  position: absolute;
  top: 290px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;

  padding: 10px 200px;

  font-family: "Adelle PE";
  line-height: 1.379;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 0.300em;
  text-align: center;

  border-style: solid;
  color: red;
}

.chrisdavenport-middle24-text:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/csybh5ze/3/

Answer (score 0):

Well you may use `text-indent: 12px` in your code.