# In css is there a way to get the content of a tag?

Tags: css

Is it possible to get the content of a tag using content in css?

```
a::after {
    content: whatever is contained within the a tag
}
```

I am trying to implement [Inline elements shifting when made bold on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556153/inline-elements-shifting-when-made-bold-on-hover)

Comment: What you mean with body of a tag? Html is build using elements. `:after` is a pseudo element. Beside that css is a tool to create styles not to retrieve data. Javascript is used for that. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Unsure if you can do this with pure CSS, but it can be achieved by mixing it with JavaScript. @MarkBaijens my guess is he means whatever content is within the tag (going by his sugar code example).

Comment: I'm afraid not. Only `attr` from CSS can get element attributes.
https://davidwalsh.name/css-content-attr 
In addition, this `attr` only support `content` attribute.
https://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-attr

Comment: better use javascript

Comment: thanks i've updated the question. I ended up using attr(title)