# How to avoid expanding the parent flex element on hover

Tags: css, flexbox

I have simple nav bar list and i need change item font weight on hover. But when I hover on item its width changes so other nav items position changes too. How to fix this issue?

Exampe:

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav__item {
  font-weight: 100;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav__item:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<html>
<div class="container">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="nav__item">Home</li>
    <li class="nav__item">About</li>
    <li class="nav__item">Contacts</li>
    <li class="nav__item">Donate</li>
    <li class="nav__item">FAQ</li>
  </ul>
</div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

An easy way is to set a vertical or horizontal `text-shadow` to mimic bold letters, `transform` with `skew()` or `scale()`, ... could also help making effects witouth having every thing jump .

example with an horizontal `text-shadow`

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items:center;
  list-style: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav__item {
  font-weight: 100;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav__item:hover {
 text-shadow: 1px 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
<div class="container">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="nav__item">Home</li>
    <li class="nav__item">About</li>
    <li class="nav__item">Contacts</li>
    <li class="nav__item">Donate</li>
    <li class="nav__item">FAQ</li>
  </ul>
</div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help you out:
[Inline elements shifting when made bold on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556153/inline-elements-shifting-when-made-bold-on-hover)

Although flex isnt used in this example, the top voted solution should prove to be a working work around as the li elements's width won't react to the change in width caused by the font weight change.